# Does the 'scam' scene in Don't Look Up refer to anything?

Tags: dont-look-up

In the movie ["Don't look up"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11286314/)(2021) when the main protagonists are waiting in the White House to talk to the President, the older uniformed general that is waiting with them sells them snacks.

Later they find out the snacks were actually free.

This incident bugs the main character Kate Dibiasky, and she discusses it with others a few times in the remainder of the movie.

Does this scam reference anything in American movies or popular culture in general? Is it just random?
It could be a reference to human greed and abuse of power in general, and thus fit in with the main theme of the movie.

Answer (score 9):

To me it was just another way of showing the false sense of attention the different protagonists are putting on things. Low attention span and an ill-focused behaviour on both sides.

1. the general should have a comfortable income to not rely on selling snacks to anybody
2. the general should have the self-value to not belittle himself to a petty scam
3. the general should have more important duties to attend to than selling snacks
4. the end of the world is at stake and there should be nothing more important to him
5. the scientists should also not lose their focus, yet they do. the snacks distract them first and later the scam

It is also a way of showing that many things in todays society might be coated as politeness, decency and generousity, yet when you look behind the facade, the provider is actually the main beneficiary.

Having said that, the movie does play a game of hit and miss when it comes to references and metaphors. I would chalk this one up as one of the more low-brow parts of the movie. Unless some deeper meaning eluded me.

Comment: Could there also be a comment about the value that many Americans place on capitalism, materialism, and money in this scene?

Comment: How dare you attack my people with apt observations.

Comment: I think your observations are correct. It also adds an element of absurdist humor. It's funny because it doesn't make any sense. I mean really, why would a general in the US Army sell free snacks to guests in the White House???

Comment: One could argue it's an example of how the government's resources are being sold off in a bid for capitalist privatization and self-enrichment by high placed officials (similar claims have recently been made in the real world), which contributes to the core plot of everyone having selfish priorities over the common good. However, it's not 100% clear if that was in the writers' minds or not. I reckon it was, but I cannot prove that.

Comment: @SethR This reminds me of The Naked Gun!

Comment: Would be even funnier if it happened in the Kremlin.

Comment: @StefanH it is always easier to laugh at others than to laugh about yourself. Also i doubt that they have snacks in the Kremlin.

Comment: @BestGuess No need to laught at myself as I seriously sell free stuff to my guests, but please don't tell anyone. Btw at least Putin has a, nowadays famous, cook, I bet he would have taken care of snacks.  And apart from the communist past, do you have any idea how they run business in Russia? It follows basically a similar pattern as selling free snacks...

Comment: @StefanH i was taking a stab at the Kremlin having to save every penny to pay for their futile aggressive warmongering. But maybe you are right and they are writing bills to their guests now.

Comment: @BestGuess Oh, sure they have to save every penny. On the order of General Corruptovitch, they sell their precious equipment and rations in military surplus stores overseas to get more pennies,  see https://www.reddit.com/r/NonCredibleDefense/comments/z030jd/my_favorite_part_is_it_was_made_after_the_war/

Comment: It's not surprising that a metaphor or two fell short. The movie is hilarious, but its *central* metaphor is a little lacking. It's meant to be a satire of people's attitudes towards climate change, an anthropogenic catastrophe that, according to reputable estimates, could cause 100 million deaths by 2100, disproportionately in lower-income countries. So naturally, the film is about a *natural* catastrophe that will kill *everyone* equally on a very short timetable. Transplanting a variety of people and ideas from the first situation to the second means that they end up making less sense.

Answer (score 5):

> It could be a reference to human greed and abuse of power in general, and thus fit in with the main theme of the movie.

The general is listed in the credits as "[General Themes](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt11286314/characters/nm0002117)" so the filmmakers are telling us that he does represent the main themes of the movie, and not a pop-culture reference.

We can see the meaning of this theme from Kate Dibiasky's pondering:

> "He’s a three-star general. He works at the Pentagon. Why would he charge us for free snacks?"
> "He knew eventually that I was going to find out that the snacks were free. You know what I mean? So it was just like a power play"

The general represents powerful people who needlessly take advantage of people for profit, despite not needing the money in any way. Other reviewers have made [similar](https://www.quirkybyte.com/blog/2022/01/why-the-general-in-dont-look-up-charged-for-free-snacks/) [analyses](https://screenrant.com/dont-look-up-kate-general-free-food-running-joke/).